# Timesnapper for Mac

Tags: macos, software-rec, screenshot, recording

does a similar application to Timesnapper for Mac exist?

Comment: You would get better response if you explained what Timesnapper does, or more precisely what Timesnapper features you're after.

Comment: Were you successful?

Comment: no, not really , and I think youranswer is the best

Comment: Try [SoftwareRecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm happy to announce that the official version of TimeSnapper for Mac is now available! You can find a link to it on the Mac App Store at http://timesnapper.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should work http://timesheet-mac.en.softonic.com/mac

Comment: It looks like TimeSnapper has released an official Mac version now at [www.timesnapper.com](http://www.timesnapper.com)

Comment: Has anyone tried Timesnapper for Mac? I really like Timesnapper and bought the Pro license for Windows years ago. I wish I could use the same license but I'd really not mind too much having to pay for the Mac version if someone can confirm it works as well. As of this writing there are no reviews on the mac app store.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a bash script which takes screen-shots every few seconds, combines them into an mp4 every hour, and combines the hourly mp4s into daily ones each day.

Uses ImageMagick to overly the current time on each screenshot, and ffmpeg to combine the screenshots into videos.

http://damianblog.com/2015/05/26/macblackbox/

Answer (score 1):

ManyTricks have recently released [Time Sink](http://manytricks.com/timesink/). It sounds like it does some of what Timesnapper can. No screenshots though.

If you really want the actual screenshots you could try looking into scripting it using AppleScript and launchd. Shouldn't be that difficult to do.

Comment: yes, I think scripting is the right thing and the most customizable one, thanks a lot. But I do not want to learn applescript, I do alredy know now bash and so

Comment: @user10826: Then use what you know. `screencapture -x filename.png` in a bash script, have it called regularly using `launchd` or `cron`, you're done.

Comment: I did this, but took it a step further to combine the images into mp4s using ffmpgeg http://damianblog.com/2015/05/26/macblackbox/